# Execution stop after dispatchevents called

Tags: javascript, jquery, export, jquery-events

In the below code I have exported the canvas image and need to set that image in the web page. However the execution stops once it is exported that is execution stops after calling `pom.dispatchEvent(e);` the following line is not executed.

```
$("#Digital").attr("src", 'C:\Users\labuser\Downloads' + img + '.PNG');
```

Please help me...

```
blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "image/png" });
var pom = document.createElement('a');
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
pom.href = url;
pom.setAttribute('download', img + '.png');
if (document.createEvent) {
     e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
     e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
     pom.dispatchEvent(e);
}
$("#Digital").attr("src", 'C:\Users\labuser\Downloads' + img + '.PNG');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the $ is a Jquery call, it will fail silently if incorrect.